# Android Studio Kotlin: RecyclerView with multiple viewtypes with different data

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am creating a RecyclerView that contains multiple view types. The First viewType (ViewType1) takes a productName, price and quantity. While the second viewType (ViewType2) takes productName, price and quantity, topping1, topping2, topping3, topping 4.

However, when adding entries to the recyclerview I am recieving an error for no value passed for the parameters topping1 to 4:

```
list.add(DataModel("American","1","12.50", ItemAdapter.NO_TOPPING))  //Error recieved for missing params
list.add(DataModel("Romana","1","12.50", "Pepperoni", "Aubergine", "Ex Mozz.", "Salami", ItemAdapter.TOPPINGS_4))
```

It is expecting it to be ViewType2 while it is ViewType1. How can I change it so that ViewType1 does not need to include empty parameters and only needs to pass the data parameters productName, productPrice & productQuantity.

**MainActivity.kt**

```
package com.example.multiplerecyclerview

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.item_custom_row.view.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        //Set the LayoutManager that this RecyclerView will use.
        recycler_view_items.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)

        // Adapter class is initialized and list is passed in the param.
        val itemAdapter = ItemAdapter(this, getItemsList())

        //adapter instance is set to the recyclerview to inflate the items.
        recycler_view_items.adapter = itemAdapter
    }

    private fun getItemsList(): ArrayList<DataModel> {
        val list = ArrayList<DataModel>()

        list.add(DataModel("Romana","1","12.50", "Pepperoni", "Aubergine", "Ex Mozz.", "Salami", ItemAdapter.TOPPINGS_4))
        list.add(DataModel("American","1","12.50", ItemAdapter.NO_TOPPING))

        return list
    }
}
```

**DataModel.kt**

```
package com.example.multiplerecyclerview

class DataModel(val itemName: String, val itemQuantity: String, val itemPrice: String, val topping1: String,  val topping2: String,  val topping3: String,  val topping4: String, val viewType: Int) {
}
```

**ItemAdapter.kt**

```
package com.example.multiplerecyclerview

import android.content.Context
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.item_custom_row.view.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.item_custom_row4.view.*


class ItemAdapter(val context: Context, val items: ArrayList<DataModel>) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {

    companion object {
        const val NO_TOPPING = 1
        const val TOPPINGS_4 = 4
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        if(viewType == NO_TOPPING) {
            return ViewHolder(
                LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(
                    R.layout.item_custom_row,
                    parent,
                    false
                )
            )
        } else if (viewType == TOPPINGS_4) {
            return ViewHolder4(
                LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(
                    R.layout.item_custom_row4,
                    parent,
                    false
                )
            )
        } else {
            return ViewHolder(
                LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(
                    R.layout.item_custom_row,
                    parent,
                    false
                )
            )
        }
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val item = items.get(position)

        if(holder is ViewHolder) {

            holder.productQuantity.text = item.itemName
            holder.productName.text = item.itemName
            holder.productPrice.text = item.itemPrice

        } else if(holder is ViewHolder4) {

            holder.productQuantity4.text = item.itemName
            holder.productName4.text = item.itemName
            holder.productPrice4.text = item.itemPrice

            holder.topping1.text = item.topping1
            holder.topping2.text = item.topping2
            holder.topping3.text = item.topping3
            holder.topping4.text = item.topping4
        }

    }

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        return items[position].viewType
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return items.size
    }

    class ViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        val productQuantity = view.productQuantityView
        val productName = view.productNameView
        val productPrice = view.productPriceView
    }

    class ViewHolder4(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        val productQuantity4 = view.productQuantityView4
        val productName4 = view.productNameView4
        val productPrice4 = view.productPriceView4

        val topping1 = view.topping1View
        val topping2 = view.topping2View
        val topping3 = view.topping3View
        val topping4 = view.topping4View
    }
}
```

**item_custom_row**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/cardViewItem1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_margin="4dp"
    app:cardElevation="10dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
    app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="12dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/productQuantityView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
            android:text="1"
            android:textColor="#881b32"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/productNameView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="46dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/productQuantityView"
            android:text="12'' Killiney Beach"
            android:textColor="#881b32"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/productPriceView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="52dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/productNameView"
            android:text="14.50"
            android:textColor="#fcac52"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

**item_custom_row4**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/cardViewItem4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_margin="4dp"
    app:cardElevation="10dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
    app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="12dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/productQuantityView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
            android:text="1"
            android:textColor="#881b32"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/productNameView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="46dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/productQuantityView4"
            android:text="12'' Killiney Beach"
            android:textColor="#881b32"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/productPriceView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="52dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/productNameView4"
            android:text="14.50"
            android:textColor="#881b32"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/topping1View"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/productPriceView4"
            android:text="Pepperoni"
            android:textColor="#fcac52"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/topping2View"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/topping1View"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/productPriceView4"
            android:text="Aubergine"
            android:textColor="#fcac52"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/topping3View"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/topping1View"
            android:text="Semi Dried Tomatos"
            android:textColor="#fcac52"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/topping4View"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/topping1View"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/topping2View"
            android:text="Smoked Applewood"
            android:textColor="#fcac52"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign default values to your parameters:

```
class DataModel(val itemName: String, 
val itemQuantity: String, 
val itemPrice: String, 
val topping1: String = "", 
val topping2: String = "", 
val topping3: String = "",  
val topping4: String = "", 
val viewType: Int) {
    }
```

---

you can refactor this to be a data class

```
data class DataModel(val itemName: String,
val itemQuantity: String,
val itemPrice: String, 
val topping1: String = "",  
val topping2: String = "",  
val topping3: String = "",  
val topping4: String = "", 
val viewType: Int)
```

you could also make use of nullable variables here, since they are potentially null:

```
data class DataModel(val itemName: String,
val itemQuantity: String, 
val itemPrice: String, 
val topping1: String? = null,
val topping2: String? = null,  
val topping3: String? = null, 
val topping4: String? = null, 
val viewType: Int)
```

Then, because kotlin has named arguments, you can do this:

```
  val foo = DataModel("American","1","12.50", viewType = ItemAdapter.NO_TOPPING )
```